# How to get dependency graph for dependencies of a target?

Tags: bazel

I want to get mutual dependencies of all dependencies of a target, to provide this information to a binary (for static analysis).

I defined a rule that loop through direct dependencies. How can I get dependencies of each dependency, to discover the entire graph recursively? Is it possible at all? If no, is there an alternative way?

```
def _impl(ctx):
    
    for i, d in enumerate(ctx.attr.deps):
        # I need to get dependencies of d somehow here
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly what information you want, Aspects may do what you want:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html

They allow a rule to collect additional information from transitive dependencies.

There's also the `genquery` rule, but this may or may not give you all the information you want: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genquery

`genquery` makes bazel query results available to actions.

Comment: Yes, aspects would sound as a right direction, if it was possible to loop through all transitive dependencies of a target, in a rule. I feel it may be a problem. Do you happen to know an example?

Comment: Another option is to use aspects with genquery. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: It's a little tricky to give an example because the details might matter here. What kind of dependencies will there be, is this Java, C++, custom rules, or something else? What information does the static analyzer need? Source files, Java class files, .a/.o files, etc? Does the analyzer need all the information at once, or can it run incrementally on individual dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I need to pass parameter --output=graph to `genquery`:

```
blaze query "kind(rule, deps(//path/to/mytarget))" --output=graph
```